# How can I double-query two mongoose values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a `buildQuery` to get posts for a social feed.

When users make a post, their university is saved in the post as `university`. They can also choose to make sure that ONLY other students from their same university can see it.

If they want to do so, then `uniOnly` is set to `true` on the post model.

Here's part of the `PostSchema`:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  university: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  uniOnly: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  }
});
```

In the `buildQuery` below, the university, `uni` of the user, (stored in their profile document) requesting the feed is passed in as an parameter.

So what I'm trying to do is check that IF `uniOnly` is set to `true` on the post and the `uni` coming in is NOT the same as `university` on the post, then it should NOT be seen in the feed.

How can I do this? Should I be using `$where`? Or an if statement some 
how?:

```
const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
  const { uni } = criteria;
  const query = {};

  // Should I be using $where?
  query.uniOnly = { $where: }

  return query;
};
```

The `buildQuery` is quite large so I've cut it down to what is relevant.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query for posts where `uniOnly = false` OR `university = criteria.uni`, then you can use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) to combine the terms logically:

```
const buildQuery = (criteria) => {
  const query = { $or: [ {uniOnly: false}, {university: criteria.uni} ] };
  return query;
};
```

Comment: If it's `uniOnly = false`, then the post can only be queried IF `university = criteria.uni`.

This does the same thing right?

Comment: @bloppit It gets the `uniOnly = false` docs, as well as the docs where `university = criteria.uni` (and an implied `uniOnly = true` presuming that's the only other option for `uniOnly`).